# How can I build a heap for a set of elements by using priority_queue class in c++?

Tags: c++11

If we want to build a heap for a set of elements, make_heap takes O(n). How can I do the same using priority_queue class?

Thank you.

Comment: The same _what_? Are you asking what's the time complexity of building an std::priority_queue of n elements?

Comment: @einpoklum, yes. can I build a heap in O(n) time using priority_queue class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr: It's possible, but not guaranteed.

AFAICT, it is theoretically possible for a C++ standard library to build its heap in linear (O(n)) time - if you construct the priority queue from a container pair for a range of n elements; see the last constructors specified [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue). However, I don't know that a standard library implementation is required to do so.

If you insert just one element at a time, using the `push()` method, you're ensuring the heap is valid after each insertion; and you may need to perform as much as log(i) of work each time for that purpose, or Omega(n*log(n)) overall (to see with this is, note that for i >= n/2, log(i)>= log(n)-1 , so you have at least n/2 * (log(n)-1) work).